# Problems with Ibus & Ibus-hangul in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, language-support, ibus, input-method

I am relatively new to Linux, but I have had Ibus working with Hangul (Korean) input in the past with Linux Mint 16 & Ubuntu 14.04

I have just installed Kubuntu 14.04 but can't get Ibus to run Hangul properly. Since installing, I now also have missing characters both in hangul & english inputs. Both in Terminal and GUI, some prgrams simply show black or white squares where english or korean characters should be.

I have tried removing Ibus and reinstalling to no effect.
im-config, in particular does not show characters properly, nor have I been able to us it; it just seems to crash when I try to change the input method.

Dolphin is also messed up.

Unfortunately I can't upload pics yet (due to reputation restriction).

Any help, please use laymen terms! Thanks :)

Output from **im-config -m**

ibus
missing
ibus

Output from **env | grep IM_**

CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
QT4_IM_MODULE=ibus
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the output from the commands `im-config -m` and `env | grep IM_`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is really a guess (and of course untested), but I notice that the QT_IM_MODULE environment variable is set to xim. You may want to try to set it to ibus, e.g. via this command:

```
echo 'export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus' > $HOME/.kde/env/qt.sh
```

Then, after a relogin, you'll possibly notice a difference.

*Edit:*

Btw, you said that you **just** installed Kubuntu 14.04. Have you updated your system after the installation?

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. Changed the QT_IM_Module to Ibus, but didn't help.
Yes, I had installed all updates after installing. i will try again though.

env | grep IM_

CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim

QT_IM_MODULE=ibus

IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1

QT4_IM_MODULE=ibus

GTK_IM_MODULE=xim

Comment: @user292444: Ok, it was a long shot. Then you'd better remove that qt.sh file. Hopefully someone else can provide more useful help.